# Is $\iint \dfrac{1}{z} dxdy\neq 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am trying to solve an exercise and at some point I came accross the integral

$$\iint_L \dfrac{1}{z} dxdy,$$
($z=x+iy$) where $L\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a compact set with positive two-dimensional Lebesgue measure. If this integral is not zero, then the excercise is solved. But is this true? Note that $\dfrac{1}{z}$ is locally integrable.

Comment: Whether or not the integral is $0$ depends on $L$. If $L$ is a disk or an annulus with centre $0$, then the integral is $0$, for example. If $L$ is a small square with centre $1$, then the integral is not $0$.

Comment: $L$ in my excercise is a cantor type set with positive measure.

Comment: Even then, it depends. If it is symmetric with respect to $0$, then the integral vanishes, if $L \neq -L$, the integral may still vanish for specific $L$.

Comment: @DanielFischer What if we define the function $g(z)=\iint_L \dfrac{1}{z-w}dm(w)$. This function is not identically $0$ right?

Comment: Right. But of course it can have zeros (it usually has), and those correspond to translates $L'$ of $L$ for which your integral in the question vanishes.

Comment: I guess your ultimate goal is to show that $g \not \equiv 0$?

Comment: Exactly! Although it seems obvious that it is not identicaly $0$ I still cannot prove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral

$$\int_L \frac{1}{z}\,dx\,dy$$

may or may not vanish, that depends on $L$. For most $L$, the integral will be nonzero, but for example if $L = -L$, then by symmetry the integral vanishes.

As mentioned in the comments, the true purpose of the question is to show that

$$g(z) := \int_L \frac{1}{z-w}\,dm(w)$$

does not vanish identically.

This can be shown using standard estimates. For large $\lvert z\rvert$, consider

$$\frac{m(L)}{z} - g(z).$$

Say $L \subset D_R(0)$, and $\lvert z\rvert > 2R$. Then we have $\lvert z-w\rvert > \frac{1}{2} \lvert z\rvert$ for $w \in L$, and so

\begin{align}
\biggl\lvert \frac{m(L)}{z} - g(z)\biggr\rvert
&= \biggl\lvert \int_L \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z-w}\,dm(w)\biggr\rvert\\
&\leqslant \int_L \biggl\lvert \frac{1}{z} - \frac{1}{z-w}\biggr\rvert\,dm(w)\\
&= \int_L \frac{\lvert w\rvert}{\lvert z\rvert\,\lvert z-w\rvert}\,dm(w)\\
&\leqslant \frac{2R}{\lvert z\rvert^2}m(L)\\
&< \frac{m(L)}{\lvert z\rvert},
\end{align}

which implies $g(z) \neq 0$ for $\lvert z\rvert > 2R$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and for your patience!

Comment: I just realised that quite easily we can see that $lim_{z\to\infty} zg(z)=m(L)>0$ and thus $g$ is not identically zero.