# Complex: If $|f|<\varepsilon$, then $\frac{1}{\pi}\int_E \frac{|f|}{|z-w|}<\varepsilon$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Is this true?

Let $f:E\xrightarrow{}\mathbb{C}$ be holomorphic on the interior of a compact set $E$, and let $\varepsilon>0.$

If $|f|<\varepsilon$ on $E$, then $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_E \frac{|f(w)|}{|z-w|} dm(w)<\varepsilon$$ for $z\in E$, where $m$ is the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure.

Important edit: $E$ is COMPACT.

Comment: Is $z \in \Bbb E$?

Comment: Correctt $z\in E$

Comment: This may be of interest: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1808376/is-iint-dfrac1z-dxdy-neq-0?rq=1

Comment: Did you neglect to divide by $2\pi$?

Comment: Ahh, yes, I did neglect that. My apologies, it's fixed now.

Comment: It looks quite false to me. Take $z=0$ and $E$ a disk of large radius centered at $0$. Use polar coordinates, of course.

Comment: Right you are @Ted. What if $z\neq 0$?

Comment: It's only going to change a tiny bit if you vary $z$ a little :)

Answer (score 1):

Less than $\epsilon$ looks very unreasonable. If $E$ is the closed unit disk, $w=0$ and $f(x)=\epsilon /2$ for all $x$ then the left side is $\pi \epsilon $ which is greater than $\epsilon$.

Comment: I amended my statement to include $\frac{1}{\pi}$, my apologies